# How can I configure Craft security so that my site can be embedded in an iframe?

Tags: security, embed

**Context**

I'm embedding a specific "contact us" page from our marketing site into our web application using an iframe. Our marketing site is the primary domain, while the web application exists on a subdomain (but same top level domain).

When embedding the form page, the browsers refuses to render it because Craft automatically sets `X-Frame-Options` to `sameorigin`.

**Browser message**

`Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

**Attempted Fixes**

I have tried updating our CSP in nginx to allow for the subdomain, however `X-Frame-Options` remains present so the browser never allows the embed.

`add_header Content-Security_Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' *.oursite.com https://localhost:4200;";`

I have tried:

- Using `proxy_hide_header 'X-Frame-Options';` in our config
- Attempting to set `{% header "X-Frame-Options: ''" %}` in my index.twig

Answer (score 1):

**And it was user rrror**

It helps to spell "Content-Security-Policy" correctly.

**However, if you still have issues with X-Frame-Options**

We are using a docker image for craft which includes an nginx partial: `craftcms/security.conf`

https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft/blob/master/nginx-partials/security.conf

Within that file is the X-Frame-Options header. The solution was to remove the reference to `craft/security.conf` and migrate its contents to our `default.conf`.

You can then remove the `X-Frame-Options` header and inserted your own CSP.